# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion only on PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7

I am a newbie of PHP. I study it from `php.net`, but I found a problem today.

```
class foo {
    var $bar = 'I am bar.';
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = 'bar';
$baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
echo "{$foo->$bar}\n";
echo "{$foo->$baz[1]}\n";
```

The documentation(http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) say that the above example will output:

```
I am bar.
I am bar.
```

But I get the different output run on my PC(PHP 7):

```
I am bar.
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in ... on line <b>9</b><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: foo::$Array in ... on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Why?

Comment: The reference to **People** in the error message, but absence **People** in the code is confusing to say the least.

Comment: Here are the official documentation on [the changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should work with PHP 7:

```
class foo {
var $bar = 'I am bar.';
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = 'bar';
$baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
echo "{$foo->$bar}\n";
echo "{$foo->{$baz[1]}}\n";
```

This is caused because in PHP 5 the following line:

```
echo "{$foo->$baz[1]}\n";
```

is interpreted as:

```
echo "{$foo->{$baz[1]}}\n";
```

While in PHP 7 it's interpreted as:

```
echo "{{$foo->$baz}[1]}\n";
```

And so in PHP 7 it's passing the entire array to `$foo` instead of just that element.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign array to a variable and use that variable on function call. That will work... I fixed this issue in that way.

Because when coming to PHP 7, that will pass whole array when we directly used it on function call.

EX:

```
$fun['myfun'](); // Will not work on PHP7.

$fun_name = $fun['myfun'];
$fun_name();    // Will work on PHP7.
```