# Sessions not working in localhost but work in live server (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have been facing this issue since yesterday and yet I could not resolve this. Issue is sessions are not working in local environment but when for a testing purpose I put the same files on a live server, they work all okay.

Here if my **config.php** file:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Here is how I save the data in one of my model files

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user',$result); //$result works fine, it produces
right result
```

In my view, I tried to access this by:

```
$this->session->userdata['user']['name']; //name here is an element in result array
```

I get this error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: user
>
> Filename: home/home.php
>
> Line Number: 2

To my surprise, this same code runs without any error on server.

**Also**, to be able to know the data being saved by Codeigniter sessions, I tried database method.

I changed the code to below in **config.php** file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Instead of inserting one row of data, it inserts four. Please see below screenshot from the database (last four rows).

[image: Database Screenshot]

Can anybody point to the error? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add a debug line `print_r($this->session->userdata);` and see exactly what is in the session

Comment: Here is the output: Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1505985569 )

Comment: Is your local database the exact same as your production one? The tables are the same names etc?

Comment: Exact, just because it was not working in local, I tried putting it online to verify with the same database and files, it worked there

Comment: If it helps, I'm using PHP version 7.1 and CI version 3.1.6

Comment: try a print_r($this->ci->session->userdata()). Also see if browser accept your cookie from local domain, because browsers sometimes do not. If possible give a hostname with dot inside to your machine.

Comment: Please check the permission of your folder, sometimes the folder permission is cause to error. Try and set the $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] from FALSE to TRUE, then it should work.

Comment: Try increasing log level to 4, enable CI logging and inspect new log entries. Enable debug to inspect session data with $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

Comment: what is your php version?

Answer (score 5):

Your question has a few parts, I'll answer each in turn.

#### Regarding retrieving values from the session

`userdata()` is a method.  The way you are accessing it treats it as an array:

```
$this->session->userdata['user']['name']; // Bad
```

[As the docs describe](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=set_userdata#retrieving-session-data), you should pass the key of the value you want to retrieve as a parameter to the `userdata` method:

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('user');
// Now you can echo $user['name'];
```

Even simpler is to use the newer syntax:

```
$user = $this->session->user;
// Now you can echo $user['name'];
```

#### Regarding the 4 session records in the database

Check the `timestamp` fields.  They show 3 different times, meaning those are 3 separate events on the site.  The first occurs at `1501911275`, then 6 seconds later there are another 2 records, and then 139 seconds later the last record.  Those represent 3 separate requests to the site - probably you were visiting different pages, or testing and reloading.

As to *why* there are multiple records, that's because the session ID is periodically regenerated.  Exactly how often that happens depends on your configuration see the [`sess_time_to_update`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences) config option.  How often they are destroyed also depends on your config (see `sess_regenerate_destroy` in the same section of the docs) - but normally older session records stick around for a while and are cleaned up later by garbage collection.  So while you have only 1 "current" session record, old records can persist for a while.

#### Regarding your `sess_save_path`

From the wording of your question I think you want to use the `files` session driver, and only tried the `database` driver for testing.  If that's correct, there is a problem in your files session configuration which you should fix.

[According to the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver):

> only absolute paths are supported for $config['sess_save_path'].

The comments in [`config/config.php`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L342) also say:

> WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!

Your configuration specifies that session data should be saved in `ci_sessions`, which is not an absolute path:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; // Bad
```

I am not sure how will be interpreted, but my guess is the directory won't exist, and the web server will not have permissions to create it.  I can't imagine why it works on your live server.

Change the path to an absolute path, and make sure your web server can write to it.  [Again from the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver)

```
mkdir /<path to your application directory>/sessions/
chmod 0700 /<path to your application directory>/sessions/
chown www-data /<path to your application directory>/sessions/
```

(change `www-data` to the user your web server is running as).  And then:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/<path to your application directory>/sessions/';
```

Comment: @shanil Does this help?

Comment: No, I tried everything what all suggested but nothing was working. Finally, I found the issue, CI 3.1.6 was not supporting PHP 7.1, when I moved back to 5.6, it started saving the session. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ShanilSoni I just set up a Docker container with PHP 7.0 and a fresh install of Codeigniter 3.1.6, and sessions work fine. I don't think it is a PHP version problem.

Comment: @ShanilSoni If you tried everything suggested here you would have seen that neither of the other 2 answers here actually work, right?

Comment: That's why I mentioned in my own answer that maybe this is not the correct explanation but that worked somehow. Yes, none of the answers mentioned here did work. This error I have been trying to resolve past 15 days and for the pages that required sessions to be read, I commented out that code to have that worked otherwise.

Comment: @ShanilSoni OK ... I meant that the other 2 answers here not only don't solve your problem, but will throw errors, they include bad PHP.  That's why I wondered if you really had tried them.  If you also tried everything in my answer and it didn't help then I am stumped :-)  Good luck in any case.

Comment: Just f.y.i., The problem I mostly encounter when going from PHP 5 to 7 is when arrays are passed to a method as a variable using `method($arr['param'])` which will break in PHP 7 when something else than an array is expected. You should first define a variable and then pass it to a method. Maybe one of the functions needed here are doing this that way. See the answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906624/php-notice-array-to-string-conversion-only-on-php-7
You should see a notice in your error log (if enabled) if this is the case.

Comment: I got this issue when in my webhosting I select PHP 7.0, then I change to 7.2, after that the sessions works!

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for the detailed answer, i am facing similar issue and i have noticed that for each page refresh there is a new entry created in ci_sessions table. I recently have started dabbling in php, can you pls suggest how should i debug? I'm working on a code igniter application, using database for persisting sessions. Live site works but when i test changes on my local machine using ngrok it start acting weird...

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Codeigniter Class Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#class-reference)  `setuserdata` expects the second argument to be a value, that in case first argument is a key, hence the error.

with the Codeigniter way, you won't be able to achieve what you want as it uses:

[set](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#CI_Session::set_userdata) like this:

`$result=array('name'=>'john doe');`

`$this->session->set_userdata($result);` or `$this->session->set_userdata('name','john doe');`

[get](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#CI_Session::userdata) like this:

`echo $this->session->userdata(['name']);`

on the other hand using vanilla php `$_SESSION` you can achieve it like so:

set: `$_SESSION['user']=$result;`

get: `echo $_SESSION['user']['name'];`

see about $_SESSION at [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

**note:**

> To my surprise, this same code runs without any error on server.

this is due to your `ENVIRONMENT` setting, as you have `error_reporting` limited at the production (live) server. This is set in your root `index.php`.

change `define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');` to: `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` and you won't see the error on your localhost as well.

**update:**

Actually `$this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);` works, but the function userdata() only accepts one argument and expects it to be a string

if you look into session library (/system/libraries/Session/Session.php), you'll find it near row 747:

```
/**
 * Userdata (fetch)
 *
 * Legacy CI_Session compatibility method
 *
 * @param   string  $key    Session data key
 * @return  mixed   Session data value or NULL if not found
 */
public function userdata($key = NULL)
{
    if (isset($key))
    {
        return isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : NULL;
    }
    elseif (empty($_SESSION))
    {
        return array();
    }

    $userdata = array();
    $_exclude = array_merge(
        array('__ci_vars'),
        $this->get_flash_keys(),
        $this->get_temp_keys()
    );

    foreach (array_keys($_SESSION) as $key)
    {
        if ( ! in_array($key, $_exclude, TRUE))
        {
            $userdata[$key] = $_SESSION[$key];
        }
    }

    return $userdata;
}
```

Comment: No, I already tried this. And set_userdata can have the first parameter as name. I was using it with success.

Comment: @ShanilSoni please see my updated answer, if you use php $_SESSION you can resolve your problem. No error on live server is definitely your Environment setting, I've just checked it.

Comment: No, I tried everything what all suggested but nothing was working. Finally, I found the issue, CI 3.1.6 was not supporting PHP 7.1, when I moved back to 5.6, it started saving the session. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm clueless then why it was not working in my local environment. I have been facing this issue for 15 days now. When I switched back, it started working somwhow.

Comment: did you double check with setting `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` at localhost (like a wrote above). this will suppress the error message. Maybe this is what is confusing you.

Comment: @ShanilSoni I've just look into the libraries function userdata(), argument must be a string, so you cannot call it like you do, see the update

Answer (score 0):

Follow these

**In config.php**

```
Set $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

---

As you said **`$this->session->set_userdata('user',$result); //$result works fine, it produces`** above `$result` shoulb be like this

```
$result = array(
    'user'  => 'Ab',
    .....
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);
```

---

### How To Access session key

```
echo $this->session->userdata('user');
```

or

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('user');
echo $user;
```

Comment: `sess_save_path` is not supposed to be empty, ever.

Comment: @Narf check the GitHub repo https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L370-L376

Comment: You should check it more carefully yourself: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1.6/application/config/config.php#L357

Comment: It's default config, which not helps unless it changed. And this shows when its important https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1.6/application/config/config.php#L351

Comment: I don't even understand what you're trying to say with that. Nothing in there suggests that the value should be left empty.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was with PHP version 7.1 as CI 3.1.6 was not supporting that PHP version.

I'm not sure whether this is the correct explanation but when I switched back to PHP version 5.6, everything started working absolutely fine.

Comment: I just set up a Docker container with PHP 7.0 and a fresh install of Codeigniter 3.1.6, and sessions work fine.  I don't think it is a PHP version problem.

Comment: I have just had the same issue. I have just tested and works fine in PHP 7.0. But there are bugs with session data with PHP 7.1

Comment: All 3.1.x versions do support PHP 7.1. Whatever the problem was, it 100% was not that.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with access of session data with incorrect syntax.you can use below syntax for set session data and get session data.

Example for set session data

```
$session_data = array('name' => "kiran");
$this->session->set_userdata('user', $session_data);
```

Example for get stored session data

```
$this->session->userdata('user')['name'];
```

Comment: this `$this->session->userdata('user')['name'];`is incorrect! the function userdata is declared as: `public function userdata($key = NULL)`, see session library (/system/libraries/Session/Session.php), you'll find it near row 747:

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

### $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [
```

L,QSA]

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing lots of r & d work but problem not solved but suddenly I have check my MySQL version, and when I change my SQL version then it will work. If you have any problem like this you can check your version so that you can get result.