# Codeigniter Sessions not working after migration

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an application built using CodeIgniter 3.1.6. I was carrying out testing on a subdomain on the production server. I pointed the main domain to the folder and also changed $base_url in config.php to the correct URL. ($cookie_domain within config.php has never been set.)

However, session data is now not working. I have tried some testing, the session data can be set and read within one controller.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);
echo $this->session->userdata('name');
```

However this doesn't work across URLs. For example:

```
// controllers/Contact.php
$this->session->set_userdata('name', $name); 

// controllers/Welcome.php
echo $this->session->userdata('name');
```

Any ideas as to why this may not work on a different domain?

Comment: Are you sure the `$name` variable is not empty? what do you get when you `var_dump($this->session->name)`?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46855322/2275490

Comment: @Vickel. Thanks, In your link, it suggests a problem with CodeIgniter 3.1.6 and PHP 7.1 when using session data. Didnt realise the domain was running 7.1. Post it as an answer and I'll +1

Comment: @user1949366 what you mean by ***However this doesn't work across URLs***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been several issues reported for incompatibility of PHP version 7.1 and CI 3.1.6 not supporting `$this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);`

well, `$this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);` works, but the function `userdata()` accepts only one argument and expects it to be a string

if you look into session library (/system/libraries/Session/Session.php), you'll find near row

747:

```
/**
 * Userdata (fetch)
 *
 * Legacy CI_Session compatibility method
 *
 * @param   string  $key    Session data key
 * @return  mixed   Session data value or NULL if not found
 */
public function userdata($key = NULL)
{
    if (isset($key))
    {
        return isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : NULL;
    }
    elseif (empty($_SESSION))
    {
        return array();
    }

    $userdata = array();
    $_exclude = array_merge(
        array('__ci_vars'),
        $this->get_flash_keys(),
        $this->get_temp_keys()
    );

    foreach (array_keys($_SESSION) as $key)
    {
        if ( ! in_array($key, $_exclude, TRUE))
        {
            $userdata[$key] = $_SESSION[$key];
        }
    }

    return $userdata;
}
```

but alternatively you can fetch an array like `$name=array('firstname'=>'mr smith')` with native $_SESSION like this:

set:

```
$_SESSION['name']=$name;
```

or

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);
```

get:

```
echo $_SESSION['name']['firstname']; //etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

Open:
system/libraries/Session/Session.php

```
session_start(); to // session_start();
```

And Change:

```
    ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
    ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
    ini_set('session.hash_function', 1);
    ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 4);
```

To

```
  /* ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
    ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
    ini_set('session.hash_function', 1);
    ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 4); */
```

Last edit open /index.php add to top:

```
session_start();
```

**Solved.**

Comment: It's working well for me with PHP 7.4. Thank "@Limitless isa" so much