# codeigniter - unable to retrieve session variables from the already set session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am having an application where in, I set some session variables and later when I try to retrieve them, they don't exist. The solution I found on similar cases was to make the session save folder writable. In my case, the folder is actually writable, I have checked it with the following code:

```
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
}
```

Below is a snapshot of the result I get after var_dumping `$this->session` from the controller:
[image: var_dump(<code>$this->session</code>)]

Any suggestions/ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you show us how you are setting the session in your application??

Comment: @Prabhu `$this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $user_id));` This is one of the instances where I set a session.

Comment: which CI and PHP version are you using? please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490

Comment: @Vickel I am using PHP 7.1 in server and CI v3.1.1

Comment: see the link above, there have been session fixes since CI 3.1.7., on how to upgrade: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrading.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your configuration. Specifically this line

```
$config['sess_save_path']  = NULL;
```

Because you are using the 'files' `sess_driver` a value must be provided for `sess_save_path`.

From the [CI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver), the session class

> doesn’t support PHP’s directory level and mode formats used in
>   session.save_path, and it has most of the options hard-coded for
>   safety. Instead, only absolute paths are supported for
>   $config['sess_save_path'].

So you need to provide the absolute path to your session files folder.

```
$config['sess_save_path']  = 'complete/path/to/sessions/';
```

You can find a controller and view that will let you easily test a session setup [HERE](https://github.com/dafriend/Codeigniter-Session-Tester).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the session as follows.

```
$session_data = array('user_id' => $user_id);
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you show me the session configurations from config file??

Comment: `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;`

Comment: @BijuPDais You need to set your session save path example `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH  . 'cache/sessions/'; ` then autload the library I would

Answer (score 0):

Try setting base_url in application/config.php, to 'http://localhost/ciappfolder'