# Codeigniter session stored in database but not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have two very simple controllers:
One is for setting session:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Ses extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
    $this->session->set_userdata('userId', 'myId');
    print_r($this->session->userdata());


    echo '<a href="'.base_url('ses2').'">Ses2</a>'; 
    }
}
```

and it print sessions:

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1537709001 [userId] => myId ) Ses2
```

So the session is set and works as it should. But, when I click the link "ses2" I have another controller:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ses2 extends CI_Controller 
    {


    function index()
    {
        print_r($this->session->userdata());
    }   
}
```

and I get:

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1537709217 )
```

So my session disappear somehow:

I'm using database to store sessions, this is my config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions1';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';//its your table name name
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Strange thing is, when I check database, bloob data is there.

I'm really confused here.

Comment: Are you loading the session library anywhere? Try putting `$this->load->library('session');` before you use the sessions in both controllers (or even in the constructor of your controllers). What looks weird is that you get different session id's.

Comment: Does the session ID stay the same when you refresh the ses page? And are you sure you don't destroy the session anywere?

Comment: I'm loading session library in autoload.php and when I refresh ses, it gives me different id

Comment: Actually, I'm using the same code (for login, this is just for testing) on few websites but here I have this problem. I guess there is some restriction with server but I have no idea where to look.

Comment: this may be an issue of CI and PHP versions, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490

Comment: Exactly, I fixed it with: [link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5363). Thanks guys, hope this will help someone, it was so frustrating for couple of days

Comment: @Pecooou it would be great if you turn your insights of your last comment into a self-answer. Then we have a question/answer pair which will most likely be found in search and help someone. Comments are, well comments: not searchable and probably due to be deleted at some time. Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was a problem with Codeigniter 3.1.6 and PHP 7.1.7. I've just upgraded CI to newest version.

Answer (score -1):

The way of setting the session variable should be like this. The second parameter should be value.

```
$myId='123';
$this->session->set_userdata('userId',$myId);
```

Comment: So you're saying that the OP needs to add the value to a variable before adding it to a session? That's not true, though. Of course you can add the value directly as the second argument. (That's the only difference I see between your example and the OP's code).

Comment: can you please try this if this is not the reason then there should be problem in defining the session

Comment: I'm confused what this offers. OP provided code that sets the userdata key of `'userid'` to be the string `'myId'`, not an arbitrary integer. Regardless, string values are acceptable...