# How to fix session being auto generated when page is reloaded/refresh using Codeigniter and Database as session driver?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have my little project running perfectly on my local computer. However, when I run it into my laptop, an entry is automatically loaded in my ci_sessions table each time the page is being reloaded or refresh. I am using the database as my session driver.

[image: Here's an example of entries being auto-added after reloading my login page (row 1-3) and after successfully logging in (row 4-6)]

Based on the screenshot: row 4 says that my login session store successfully. However, the 2 extra rows (5, 6) that are being added cause this code to fail:

```
public function isLoggedIn()
{

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') === true) {
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }
}

public function isNotLoggedIn()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') !== true) {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

here's my config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Here's my Page Controller

```
<?php 

class Pages extends MY_Controller
{
    public function view($page = 'login')
    {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        if($page == 'login') {
            $this->isLoggedIn();
            $this->load->view($page, $data);
        } 
        else{
            $this->isNotLoggedIn();

            $this->load->view($page, $data);
        }
    }

}
```

MY_Controller Class

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {

        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') === true) {
            redirect('home', 'refresh');
        }
    }   

    public function isNotLoggedIn()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') !== true) {
           redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

}
```

So far I have already tried adding the code below to my autoload.php but no luck.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Note: again this works in another unit with a similar setup.

Comment: what's the php version on localhost versus production?

Comment: working unit php version 5.6, not working unit: 7.3 php version. @Vickel

Comment: and the CI version you are using? there have been incompatibilities reported: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875979/codeigniter-sessions-not-working-after-migration/46876622#46876622

Comment: I am using 3.1.10 in both unit. I will try downgrading the php version of the 2nd unit. I will update this once I got it working. Thanks @Vickel

Answer (score 1):

after trying some work around, Codeigniter 3 is not yet compatible with php 7. I have to downgrade my php version to 5.6 to make it work. thanks folks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered a lot of troubles with the original CI session library (included what you mention). Finally I arrived to this replacement that use `native PHP session`. It works!
Believe me, in the middle of a project, I did not stop to wonder why. Just works.

Here it is: [CodeIgniter Native Session](https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Native-Session)

BUT, due that it is an old library you MUST made some hacks. You can check those simple hacks in the library's forum

Just drop this file in codeigniter's library directory.