# how to check if a value exists in codeigniter's session variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I found this piece of code on codeigniter's documentation and i was wondering if there's a codeigniter function of knowing if a value exists in the session

```
$newdata = array(
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

This session stores an array as oppose the usual single element session. 
how do i access items in this array?
how do i check if an item exists in this array?

Thanks for your responses but I'm still not satisfied. Check this out

```
if ($roles->result_array())
        {

            foreach($roles->result_array() as $key => $value)
            {

                $role[] = $value['type'];
            }
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata('role', $role);
```

with a print_r() function i get this output `Array ( [0] => admission officer [1] => subject teacher )`

when i do this   `print_r($this->session->userdata('role'))` i will get `admission officer` which is the desired output but my challenge is how to loop through this session array such that i can know the size of the array and use the index values in the loop?

something like :

```
for($i = 0; $i < $this->session->userdata('role')->length(); $i++)
{
   if($this->session->userdata('role')[$i] == 'admission officer')
   {
      some code here...
   }

}
```

Comment: `$this->session->username` if u want username basically `$this->session->key`

Comment: depending on your php version and your CI version, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490

Answer (score 0):

Hi check below code to get and set data in session
This method will store value in one variable

```
$newdata = array(
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata('new_session', $newdata);

$sessionData = $this->session->userdata('new_session');
```

Also you can get the data like this directly :

```
 $newdata = array(
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

print_r($this->session->userdata->username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the function i was looking for is sizeof(). it does the trick.

```
echo sizeof($this->session->userdata('role'));
```