# SESSION variable is reset on redirect() in Codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, wamp

I am facing some weird issue of session variable getting reset on action redirect.

I am using Codeigniter and redirecting to dashboard action after login, I am getting data in login action after verifying credentials with DB, but when I use redirect() to redirect to dashboard, session variables gets vanished.

**Admin.php**

```
<?php class admin extends CI_Controller 
{
    function login()
    {
        $login = $this->Admin_model->login($this->input->post()); // <-- verify data and set to session
        if($login)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Logged in Successfully");
            var_dump($_SESSION); // <-- able to fetch data from session
            // exit();
            redirect("admin/dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Invalid Credentials!! Please Try Again!!");
            redirect("admin");
        }
    }

    function dashboard()
    {
        var_dump($_SESSION); // <-- session data is vanished and not able to get userdata('id')
        exit();
        if($this->session->userdata('id') != '')
        {
            $data['active_tab'] = "dashboard";
        }
        else
        {
            redirect("admin");
        }
    }
?>
```

**Admin_model.php**

```
<?php Class Admin_Model extends CI_Model
{
    function login($data)
    {
        $user = $this->db->get_where("users",array("username" => $data['username'],
                                     "password" => md5($data['password']),
                                     "is_active" => "1")
                                    )->row_array(); 
        if(!empty($user))
        {
            $this->set_user_session($user);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function set_user_session($login)
    {
        $arr = array();
        $arr["id"] = $login["id"];
        $arr["username"] = $login["username"];
        $this->session->set_userdata($arr);
    }
?>
```

**Tried this in xampp and wamp, all browsers but still the issue remains the same, any help would be grateful.**

Comment: what CI version and what PHP version are you using ? does it work, if you assign values to $_SESSION array?

Comment: My CI version is **3.1.0** and php **7.2.18**

Comment: there has been problems reported in the early 3.1.x version, try to upgrade to the latest 3.1.11, see my answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490

Comment: @Vickel has the correct answer. You need to upgrade your CI version.

Comment: my same code was working and suddenly it stopped working, still, I need to update CI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of CodeIgniter are you working with? You can try the following steps.

1. Go to system/libraries/Session/Session.php
2. Comment `session_start()` by adding `//`. We want to relocate the sessionn_start().
3. Find (`using ctrl + f`) a comment that says `Security is king`. Comment out all the line under that comment until the end of the function. In my case I commented out the line number 315 - 320.
4. on line number 282 change this line `ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);` to `ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);`
5. comment out following lines

   `line 108    //session_set_save_handler($class, TRUE);
    line 290-296
       // session_set_cookie_params(
       //     $params['cookie_lifetime'],
       //     $params['cookie_path'],
       //     $params['cookie_domain'],
       //     $params['cookie_secure'],
       //     TRUE // HttpOnly; Yes, this is intentional and not configurable for security reasons
       // );
     line 305   //ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $expiration);`
6. Go to the main index.php, it is the first index.php and located in the same directory with the sub-directories 'application', 'system', 'user_guide', etc.
7. Put `session_start()` right after `< ?php`

Hope this can help you....

Comment: this gives error   `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 305`

Comment: IT WORKED.....!!!! we need to comment out some more lines for this to work, but can you explain what all things we are disabling?

Comment: PHP 7 Upgrade - * Known SESSION / COOKIE Bug-
Upgrading php 5 to php 7 will address the known session/cookie bug. It seems there is a problem with $this->session->set_userdata(); and every time you redirect, the cookie value is overridden.

Comment: @NitishLad What else you commented, can you please tell?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this->session->set_userdata()` for setting the session. `this->session-> set_ flashdata()` is used for setting flash messages which are removed after next action.

Comment: I am using same i.e. **$this->session->set_userdata($arr);** to set session variable, and it sets as well, but gets vanished after checked in dashboard action.

Answer (score 0):

The new versions of the browsers might be destroying the session because of the new cookie policy.

References
https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Whenever the cookie is required to be sent to server, the browser sees the SameSite attribute to decide if the cookie to be sent to server or blocked. For user actions, it is sent to the server but for auto-redirects, it doesn't if SameSite is set to 'Strict' or 'Lax' (Lax is going to be the default value now).

Solution:

The cookie attribute SameSite can be set to 'None' along with specifying the 'Secure' attribute to 'true'. Setting 'Secure' attribute to 'true' would require your site to run on https. Sites running with http:// protocol will not be able to set 'Secure' cookie.
Please set the 'HttpOnly' attribute to 'true' for making it accessible for http requests to the server only.

In PHP, it can be achieved as below

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/PATH/; SameSite=None', <COOKIE_DOMAIN>, true, true);