# Pass an argument in URL using render_page in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

This seems like a simple question but I haven't been able to find the relevant answer!

I'm trying to use render_page for the URL that looks like sensors/edit/20

This was my attempt, but I get the error Unable to load the requested file: sensors/edit/20.php

```
$this->common->render_page($basics,'sensors/edit/'.$sensorID,$data);
```

I tried adding $sensorID to the $data array, but then I get the error that there are too few arguments being passed to my function edit($sensorID).

Is there a way to use render_page with a URL that passes an argument?

Here is the render_page function:

```
     public function Render_page($basics=array(),$viewname="",$data=array()){
                  
        $CI =& get_instance();
        
        $CI->load->view('template/top',$basics);
        $CI->load->view('template/header');
        $CI->load->view('template/leftnav');
        
        if(is_array($viewname)){
            foreach ($viewname as $view){
                $CI->load->view($view,$data);
            }
        }
        else{
            $CI->load->view($viewname,$data);
        }

        $CI->load->view('template/footer');
     }
```

Comment: This function is not a part of the core Codeigniter. Please share this function declaration too

Comment: oh duh, I was thinking it was part of CI!  updated the post with the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because the 2nd parameter of function `$viewname` is NOT an URL, but a name of view file in **/application/views/** directory. In this case Ci search **20.php** file in **/application/views/sensors/edit/** directory which is not exist

Pass an argument in URL <del>using render_page in</del> Codeigniter:

`redirect('sensors/edit/' . $sensorID);`

Comment: I get the error that there are too many redirects when I try to use redirect.  Is there a codeigniter function that is similar to render_page but takes an argument?

Comment: uugh I also then run into the error where session data is lost after redirect and I've tried the suggestions here to no avail...there has to be a better way than redirect! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329701/session-variable-is-reset-on-redirect-in-codeigniter-php