# Codeigniter Tank_auth session not set

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, tankauth

I have tried all the ways to set the session in the Codeigniter (3.0.6) and [Tank Auth](https://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) (a plug in for Login and Registration). Nothing is working for me.

Here is my ci_session table data.

[image]

Below is my Config file info for the session.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Tank Auth config :

```
$config['login_by_username'] = TRUE;
$config['login_by_email'] = TRUE;
$config['login_record_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['login_record_time'] = TRUE;
$config['login_count_attempts'] = FALSE;
$config['login_max_attempts'] = 10;
$config['login_attempt_expire'] = 60*60*24;
```

Also I have tried to print the `$_SESSION` in a controller, but I don't see the session data after the successful login.

I have used this combination (Codeigniter and TankAuth) long back (4 years before). I did not get such issues, it was a quick setup. But now it is something different and not working.

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1597612277
)
```

Comment: what CI 3.x version? how are you setting the $_SESSION ?

Comment: @Vickel - i am sorry, i have updated question for the CI version. Also i am using db table to set the session.

Comment: OK I see, there have been session issues reported for early 3.x versions, I'd recommend to update to the latest 3.1.11, see also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490

Comment: Let me try quickly then.

Comment: @Vickel - Fantastic, It is working now without any issues. Please move your suggestion to answer section. I will accept then.

Comment: Hi Raja. Just a quick note to say that begging is not acceptable on this platform (or, indeed, anywhere else). Remember that whining and pleading at volunteers is a form of emotional blackmail. Please keep your questions neutral - recordings of woe and distress it is not helpful for future readers either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been several Session issues reported with early 3.x versions and  for incompatibility of PHP version >= 7.1 :

- https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4830

Those issues were resolved with the later releases, please just perform a quick update to CI 3.1.11.

you find further in depth details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490