# session userdata has null initials, is not inputted into the database

Tags: codeigniter

I have a code like this, the problem is when I input why the id_user value is "0".
even though the admin logged in is "1"

Is there anything missing in my script code?

**Controller**

```
public function tambah()    {
    // $this->session->set_userdata('upload_image_file_manager',true);
    $kategori = $this->kategori_m->tampil();
    $this->session->set_userdata('upload_image_file_manager',true);


    // Validasi
    $valid = $this->form_validation;

    $valid->set_rules('judul_berita','Judul','required',
        array(  'required'  => 'Judul harus diisi'));

    $valid->set_rules('isi_berita','Isi','required',
        array(  'required'  => 'Isi berita harus diisi'));

    if($valid->run()) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['gambar']['name'])) {
        $config['upload_path']   = './resch/dev/admin/assets/media/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|svg|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']      = '20480'; // 2 Mb  
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(! $this->upload->do_upload('gambar')) {
    // End validasi

    $data = array(  'head_title'        => 'Berita- Edutech Solution',
                    'title'             => 'Tambah Berita',
                    'head_menu'         => 'Berita',
                    'sub_title'         => 'Total Berita',
                    'kategori'          => $kategori,
                    'error'             => $this->upload->display_errors(),
                    'isi'               => 'superadmin/berita/tambah');

    $this->load->view('superadmin/template/wrapper_admin', $data, FALSE);
    // Masuk database
    }else{
        $upload_data                = array('uploads' =>$this->upload->data());
        // Image Editor
        $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image']     = './resch/dev/admin/assets/media/'.$upload_data['uploads']['file_name']; 
        $config['new_image']        = './resch/dev/admin/assets/media/thumbs';
        $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;
        $config['quality']          = "100%";
        $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
        $config['width']            = 360; // Pixel
        $config['height']           = 360; // Pixel
        $config['x_axis']           = 0;
        $config['y_axis']           = 0;
        $config['thumb_marker']     = '';
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $i      = $this->input;
        $slug   = url_title($i->post('judul_berita'),'dash',TRUE);

        $data = array(  'id_kategori'   => $i->post('id_kategori'),
                        'id_user'       => $this->session->userdata('user_name'),
                        'slug_berita'   => $slug,
                        'judul_berita'  => $i->post('judul_berita'),
                        'isi_berita'    => $i->post('isi_berita'),
                        'jenis_berita'  => $i->post('jenis_berita'),
                        'status_berita' => $i->post('status_berita'),
                        'gambar'        => $upload_data['uploads']['file_name'],
                        // 'icon'           => $i->post('icon'),
                        'keyword'       => $i->post('keyword'),
                        'tanggal_publish'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime($i->post('tanggal_publish'))).' '.$i->post('jam_publish'),
                        // 'tanggal_mulai'      => $i->post('tanggal_mulai'),
                        // 'tanggal_selesai'        => $i->post('tanggal_selesai'),
                        // 'urutan' => $i->post('urutan'),
                        'tanggal_post'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        );
        $this->berita_m->tambah($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', 'Data telah ditambah');
        redirect(base_url('superadmin/berita/jenis_berita/'.$i->post('jenis_berita')),'refresh');
    }}else{
        $i      = $this->input;
        $slug   = url_title($i->post('judul_berita'),'dash',TRUE);

        $data = array(  'id_kategori'   => $i->post('id_kategori'),
                        'id_user'       => $this->session->userdata('user_name'),
                        'slug_berita'   => $slug,
                        'judul_berita'  => $i->post('judul_berita'),
                        'isi_berita'    => $i->post('isi_berita'),
                        'jenis_berita'  => $i->post('jenis_berita'),
                        'status_berita' => $i->post('status_berita'),
                        'gambar'        => $upload_data['uploads']['file_name'],
                        // 'icon'           => $i->post('icon'),
                        'keyword'       => $i->post('keyword'),
                        'tanggal_publish'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime($i->post('tanggal_publish'))).' '.$i->post('jam_publish'),
                        // 'tanggal_mulai'      => $i->post('tanggal_mulai'),
                        // 'tanggal_selesai'        => $i->post('tanggal_selesai'),
                        // 'urutan' => $i->post('urutan'),
                        'tanggal_post'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        );
        $this->berita_m->tambah($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', 'Data telah ditambah');
        redirect(base_url('superadmin/berita/jenis_berita/'.$i->post('jenis_berita')),'refresh');
    }}
    // End masuk database
    $data = array(  'head_title'        => 'Berita- Edutech Solution',
                    'title'             => 'Tambah Berita',
                    'head_menu'         => 'Berita',
                    'sub_title'         => 'Total Berita',
                    'kategori'          => $kategori,
                    'isi'               => 'superadmin/berita/tambah');

    $this->load->view('superadmin/template/wrapper_admin', $data, FALSE);       
}
```

in a model like this, I feel there is no problem
**Model**

```
    public function tampil() {
    $this->db->select('berita.*, user.nama, kategori.nama_kategori, kategori.slug_kategori');
    $this->db->from('berita');
    // Join dg 2 tabel
    $this->db->join('kategori','kategori.id_kategori = berita.id_kategori','LEFT');
    $this->db->join('user','user.id_user = berita.id_user','LEFT');
    // End join
    $this->db->order_by('id_berita','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
// Tambah
public function tambah($data) {
    $this->db->insert('berita',$data);
}
```

session userdata has null initials, not inputted to the database and
because I was confused, I skip. and create a function to update, but when the update function is executed it will give an error "too few arguments to functio"
I don't understand the problem.

Comment: did you check `$this->session->userdata('user_name')`? does it have a value?

Comment: I check there is no value (NULL).

but why can it have no value. while in tables and user functions I also call session userdata (user_name).

following code in user controller: $ user_name = $ this-> session-> userdata ('user_name');

where the problem is, someone can help!

Comment: what version of CI do you use?

Comment: codeigniter 3. 
I tried the var_dump session userdata. and the result is like this: array (5) {["__ci_last_regenerate"] => int (1603110841) ["user_name"] => string (13) "testadmin1" ["email"] => string (23) "testadmin @ gmail .com "[" access_level "] => string (1)" 1 "[" upload_image_file_manager "] => bool (true)}

there should be value?

Comment: but why not Insert or update to database

Comment: if you are not using CI 3.1.11 you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442735/2275490

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try to learn it

Comment: I have tried it but the id_user data is still not updated to the database.

id_user value is "0"