# When I try to load models, the session didn't work in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I tried to load model in my controller, it seems I can't load session, the browser always show me this

`Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`

this is my controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('Account_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Login';
        $this->load->view('tamplates/auth_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('auth/login');
        $this->load->view('tamplates/auth_footer');
    } 

    public function registration()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]', [
            'is_unique' => 'This email has already register!'
        ]);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|matches[password2]',[
            'matches' => 'password do not match!',
            'min_length' => 'password too short!'
        ]);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password', 'required|trim|matches[password1]');

        if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {
            $data['title'] = 'Registration';
            $this->load->view('tamplates/auth_header', $data);
            $this->load->view('auth/registration');
            $this->load->view('tamplates/auth_footer');
        } else {
            $this->Account_model->addMemberAccount();
            
            $this->session->set_flashdata('massage', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    Congratulation, your has account been registered! Please Login! 
                </div>');
            redirect('auth');
        }
    }
}
```

my model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Account_model extends CI_Controller {
    public function addMemberAccount()
    {
        $data = [
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'image' => 'default.jpg',
                'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password1'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                'role_id' => 2,
                'is_active' => 1,
                'date_created' => time()
            ];
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }
}
```

I have tried to load the model in the method itself(in registration) and in the autoload config but it still did't work.

the problem seems to desapear only if i get rid of the other and just using requler php for the session

Comment: What is the file name of the model?

Comment: Account_model.php

Comment: besides of the typo (wrong extending of model), what is your CI version and php version?

Comment: and please explain "*the session didn't work in CI*": I only see you're setting some flashdata with `$this->session->set_flashdata`: what outcome are you expecting and what does actually fail?

Comment: @Vickel i use 3.11 CI and php 7

Comment: I'd update to CI 3.1.13 and also look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876622/2275490... anyway, your question continues to be unclear, showing where and how and which session fails....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model class should extend `CI_Model`

```
class Account_model extends CI_Model
```

Comment: it work ,thanks! oh btw do you know the error message come like this? Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Comment: Yes, CI will throw errors so that developers know what is missing and be fixed (if that answers your question `do you know the error message come like this?`)

Comment: Well I want to upvote it, but apparently the site said I need 15 reputation to cast a vote